# Jenkins managing/running THOUSANDS of jobs?

Tags: jenkins, scalability, user-experience

My company's [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) uses Jenkins at the core, configured to run about 100 jobs -- one job per one Visual Studio [solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx).

For some reason (I have yet to determine why), my manager is eager to move to a job-per-[project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165067%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (Visual Studio .csproj, that is) Jenkins configuration. This is essentially going to increase the number of jobs to **thousands**.

My immediate thought was: Even if Jenkins is capable of handling thousands of jobs, what would be the [user experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) of the folks looking at the Jenkins dashboard like?

Some mitigation could come in the form of using [tabs (views)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Custom+View+Tabs+Plugin) to make it easier on the eye and on navigation (e.g. view/tab per solution or per some other class). But still... 100 tabs?

My questions are:

- What is your experience with Jenkins managing/running thousands of jobs?
- **How did you solve the UX problem?**
- Are there other issues? (I am assuming performance is not an issue because in principle I can employ slave machines if I run out of resources).
- What are the main benefits of running a job-per-project (vs. job-per-solution)

Partial answers/insights are very much appreciated as well.